# How is it possible to log a user into a system with billions of similar data without delay?

Tags: design, database

Taking for instance Google mail and Facebook, they both have a huge database of users. It would be easy to search through a database of 100 similar logins and find a match in a second, but not in the case of Google and Facebook. When you try to sign into Facebook or GMail, given a correct credential, you will will be logged in before you even press the `Enter` key.

How is the user information queried on the mega database to provide such a quick response without delay?

Comment: The first thing is indexing (as JacquesB already pointed out). Even a normal PC can handle a few million rows, maybe even up to billions). If that's not enough you can scale by using better hardware with lots of memory (if the whole table fits into memory speed will increase dramatically). Alternately/additionally you can replicate the table over several machines and load balance between them.

Comment: Check out [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1971045) which has answers talking about index seeks.

Comment: Note that finding a user (1 out of 100 million) is a trivial task when compared to finding search results (1 out of trillions) for Google.

Comment: Around the turn of the century, I wrote a phone database on CD. Let me tell you, finding a match in a second is a challenge when the disk seek times is measured in hundreds of milliseconds.

Answer (score 11):

Are you asking how Google can locate the record for a a particular user out of billions so fast? This is basically a question of **indexing**. Say you have a database table of a billion records, and you need to locate a single record based on a user name. A naive approach would be to traverse through the table and for each record see if it matches the username. This will be slow, because you will need to check on average half a billion records before you find the one you are looking for. This will be slow.

But if you build an index where all the usernames in the database are ordered alphabetically, you can use a different approach. Instead of starting from the beginning, you start in the middle of the index and check if the username is alphabetically before or after the middle value. This tells you which half of the index contains the value searched for. So you repeat the operation again on this half the the index. Each iteration will cut the search space in half, which means you will need just 30 operations (2^30 > 1 billion) before you have located the specific record (or determined that it doesn't exist). So an appropriate database index may cut the number of operations from half a billion to just 30. And 30 operations on modern hardware will happen faster than a blink of an eye.

There are multiple ways to build and search indexes, but the above is the gist of it. It allows you to locate records very fast even in very large databases.

Comment: This approach was in mind when the question was asked. given a user name as U = "acba" and database is indexed B = [a-z] then B*{1 billion }, If you are to search U through B transversely. There are lots of decisions to make. query length is 4, must have a sequence C = ("[a][c][b][a]"). I believe the server does not just know where users with query 4 and sequence C lies, it must start from somewhere somehow to count the length, when it finds it, uses pattern C to transverse the sample data. This processes in a large data would at least take 7 seconds to complete Sir.

Comment: @Nexima360: Where do you get the 7 seconds? The approach I describe require only 30 operations where you have to compare strings character by character. This can be done in a matter of milliseconds. In most cases you don't even need to match the whole string, you just match character by character until you reach a mismatch. Eg. you only need a single character comparison to determine that "acba" is before "beef jerky" in the index.

Comment: And there are plenty of obvious improvements. Just keeping 26*26 dictionaries for `aa` to `zz` will help a lot - it cuts out the first 10 searches or so. (The logic being that this first-level search structure will remain in CPU cache, the 1/3 saving isn't really that worthwhile by itself)

Comment: You don't even have to partition by key.  Just divide all records randomly between N instances and search all in parallel.  One will return an answer and all the rest "not found".

Answer (score 4):

Validation of credentials can be done in few milliseconds for a billion users. This is because of :

1. Indexing  (reduces number of operation to just 30, for 1 billion users). More details : https://www.weheartswift.com/binary-search-applications/
2. Cache (will ensure that these 30 operations would not hit disk most of the time)

In real world, this would take 1 - 300 milliseconds (couple of disk accesses +  queuing + concurrency due to constant sign-ups and password changes).

Extreme example :

If organization can afford large-memory machines (Say machines with 200 GB memory), this would take near-zero time.

Say string containing username:password  (salted + hashed password in real systems) are stored in a Map. Querying this map to find out if a given username+password combination is valid or not, would take almost no-time. This is because Hashtable can check presence or absence in O(1) time complexity.

In other words, it does not matter if system has 100 users or 100 million or billions; passwords can be validated in near-zero time.

Following code demonstrates it with a smaller data-set (60 million username /passwords and 20 million users logging-in) . It took just 0.002 milliseonds per validation.

```
Sun Mar 20 18:40:11 IST 2016::Starting
Sun Mar 20 18:43:03 IST 2016::Generated test data, count 40000000
Doing 20000000 validations.
Sun Mar 20 18:43:30 IST 2016 Done in 26860 msecs.
0.001343 milliseconds per validation
```

Code :

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class UserValidator {

    Set<String> validCredentials=new HashSet<>();
    long numCredentials = 1000*1000*60;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    char[] validChars=null;

    public UserValidator(){
        String chars="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*~*()";
        validChars = chars.toCharArray(); 
    }

    String generateRandomString(int len){
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( len );
           for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
              sb.append( validChars[ rnd.nextInt(validChars.length) ] );
           return sb.toString();
    }

    String getRansomString(){
        int len = 4;
        len = len+rnd.nextInt(20);
        return generateRandomString(len);
    }


    void generateTestData(){
        for(long i=0;i<numCredentials;i++){
            String username=getRansomString();
            String password=getRansomString();
            String credentials=username+":::"+new String(username+":"+password).hashCode();
            validCredentials.add(credentials);
        }
    }

    boolean isValidUser(String user, String password){
        String credentials=user+":::"+new String(user+":"+password).hashCode();
        return validCredentials.contains(credentials);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserValidator u = new UserValidator();
        System.out.println(new Date().toString()+"::Starting");
        u.generateTestData();
        System.out.println(new Date().toString()+"::Generated test data, count "+u.validCredentials.size());
        int lookups=20*1000*1000;
        System.out.println("Doing "+lookups+" validations.");
        long timeStart = new Date().getTime();
        for(int i=0;i<lookups;i++){
            u.isValidUser(u.getRansomString(), u.getRansomString());
        }
        long timeEnd = new Date().getTime();
        long timeSpent = (timeEnd-timeStart);
        System.out.println(new Date().toString()+" Done in "+timeSpent+" msecs.");
        System.out.println((double)timeSpent/(double)lookups +" milliseconds per validation");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing good answers suggest indexes, but for string searches like this a `trie` works even better.  Ignore for a second the non-alphabetical names. You organize all possible names in a tree-like structure with 27 branches at each level: a-z and End-of-string. With an input like "john", you take the j branch, then the o branch, the h branch, and the n branch and finally the end-of-string entry to get john's password. That's just 5 steps.

Answer (score -5):

I have another answer hope you would like it, Have you noticed that when you write `www.google.com` in the address bar then it redirects according to location like if you are living in India, Then it will redirect you to this URL: `www.google.co.in`. Or if you are living in UK then it would redirect you to this URL `www.google.co.uk`. Or something like this. This is a trick to make google much faster. This is trick called *divide and speed* technique. Many programmer use this as first trick for speed.

Comment: Divide and speed? Do you mean divide and conquer?

Answer (score -6):

If millions of users are trying to use the database at a time then traffic data usage increases and connection becomes slow. If you try to keep all the data in separate tables then it will become very fast, as traffic data usage won't increase.

Comment: As fast as matching a single result over billions of others in a matter of second?

Comment: maybe, You Didn`t liked my answer right. If yes, I will not answer your any question in future. Sorry for answer.

Comment: #Pratyus Its not about liking your answer, I really appreciate your contribution, Your answer just repeats the same thing I said, How many possible SQL tables could you possibly create to hold Google users before things starts to get complicated? If that were true, you will have to make a connection to all the tables which is another work entirely. Multiple reflection table works well when you have small data group and want to optimize performance. But not in Big Data

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm pretty sure this simply isn't true, unless read operations lock entire database tables (which makes no sense and hopefully isn't true of any real-world databases). Having separate *databases* rather than separate tables might keep connections from slowing down as much, but of course even that won't cause traffic to "not increase", and dealing with multiple databases would create many other problems.